# How to apply a filter through the pages of an API and that all the results are stored in a state?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I need it to filter on each api page and have those results stored in a state.

I try this but only the result of the last page is being stored.

```
const [collections] = useState(["wedding", "outdoors", "portraits", "travel", "pets", "christmas", "products", "halloween"]);
const [resulPhotos, setResultPhotos] = useState([]);
const [pages, setPages] = useState(1);

useEffect(() => {

    for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            const url = `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=${i}&query=${collections[j]}&client_id=${accessKey}`
            axios.get(url).then((response) => {
                const photos = response.data.results.filter((item) => (
                    item.user.name === "Nathan Dumlao"
                )).map(item => item)
                setResultPhotos(photos)
            });
        }
    }
}, []);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are overwriting the state every time you call `setResultPhotos(photos)`. So the `ResultPhotos` will always be the last ones at the end of the loop.

You can add each filtered output by doing the following:

```
setResultPhotos(prev=>[...prev,...photos])
```

This will keep populating your `ResultPhotos` with new photos

Full useEffect would look like :

```
useEffect(() => {
  for (let j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
    for (let i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
      const url = `https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?page=${i}&query=${collections[j]}&client_id=${accessKey}`;
      axios.get(url).then((response) => {
        const photos = response.data.results
          .filter((item) => item.user.name === "Nathan Dumlao")
          .map((item) => item);
        setResultPhotos(prev=>[...prev,...photos]);
      });
    }
  }
}, []);
```

Side guess: I think you want `ResultPhotos` to be empty each time that useEffect fires. If that's the case, just reset the state back to an empty array before the loop starts

Here is an example : https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-stitch-dd8s76?file=/src/App.js